# how to update file in github via ubuntu

Tags: git, github, git-push

I made clone of my github.

and than opened few file, changed few `code`, and now i want to publish this code to my githu.com/user/repo.git repository. But when i do..

```
root@linux# cd myRepo/
root@linux# git commit -a -m "Updated footer"
root@linux# git push origin master.
```

I am getting following error :-

```
fatal: remote error: 
  You can't push to git://github.com/user/repo.git
  Use https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Please don't show me path to google, i have tried them and after failing it, i am writing them here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cloned the repository using the *read-only* URL.  Change the URL for your origin remote to the read-write URL given to you in the error message:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/user/repo.git
```

Then try pushing again.  (You may need to supply your GitHub credentials at this point.)

Comment: wow... bro, Thanks, do i have to do this for all my reopsitory.. btw how can i clone with write-only mode too..

Comment: @johnsmith Use the HTTPS or SSH clone links on GitHub.  Do not use the Git (`git://`) links.  You only need to perform this `remote set-url` operation if you cloned with the read-only URL and intend to push new commits to the GitHub repository.

Comment: Thanks will give a try to https or ssh :)